# Mysql if syntax in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with PHP & Mysql. Can I use MySQL `if-statement` instead of this. thanks.

```
if ($last_id > 0) {
    $query = mysql_query("select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and id < '".$last_id."'");
}else{
    $query = mysql_query("select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");
}
```

Comment: Have you considered: `select * from chat where chat.to = $user_id and (id < $last_id OR $last_id <= 0)`

Comment: Try it and see what happens

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I think in this case there is no match to use mysql if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this like

```
$last_id_query = '';
if ($last_id > 0) {
    $last_id_query .= " and id < '".$last_id."'";
}
$query = mysql_query("select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ".$last_id_query);
```

Comment: How the answer is differ from mine posting the same logic once again

Comment: @Veerendra see your and my answers are at the same time, may be few secs late..but I did'nt copied ur's

Answer (score 1):

You can write query with condition.

```
if ($last_id > 0) { $query="select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and id < '".$last_id."'";
}else{$query = "select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");}
$query = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it more like this

```
$query_part = '';
if ($last_id > 0) {
     $query_part = "and id < '".$last_id."'";

    $query = mysql_query("select * from chat where chat.to = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ".$query_part.");
```